# mat-datepicker show month and year only

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

This is my code. I am using Angular Material. How can I set the calendar to only display month and year?

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" readonly>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:material-ui] tag. This is meant for React Material, available at https://www.material-ui.com

Answer (score 2):

It seems this feature is recently added witha pull request

You can set the view

```
this._activeDate = this._monthView ?
this._activeDate = this._currentView == 'month' ?
```

**[PULL-REQUEST](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/8565)**

However this was possible with angularjs-material by setting the mode as

```
md-mode="month"
```

Comment: It's released on `5.1.0`, the latest version. 

Answer (score 1):

For Angular Material datepicker with month and years --

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var monthFormat =  buildLocaleProvider("MMM-YYYY");

    function buildLocaleProvider(formatString) {
        return {
            formatDate: function (date) {
                if (date) return moment(date).format(formatString);
                else return null;
            },
            parseDate: function (dateString) {
                if (dateString) {
                    var m = moment(dateString, formatString, true);
                    return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
                }
                else return null;
            }
        };
    }


  $scope.dateFields = [ 
                {
                    type: 'date',
                    required: false,
                    binding: 'applicant.expectedGraduation',
                    startView: 'month',
                    label: 'Credit Card Expiry - Year/Month picker',
                    mode: 'month',
                    locale: monthFormat
                }
    ];
});
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS material-sidenav Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body layout="row" layout-wrap flex layout-fill layout-align="start start" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <md-input-container flex="100" layout="column">
          <div style="font-size: 10px; color: blue;" label ng-bind="::dateFields[0].label"></div>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields[0].selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields[0].required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields[0].locale"
                     md-mode="{{dateFields[0].mode}}"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
</body>

</html>
```

For a demonstration use below link--
https://plnkr.co/edit/zXhgq3?p=preview

Answer (score -2):

Sajeetharan,

```
this._activeDate = this._monthView ?
this._activeDate = this._currentView == 'month' ?
```

how to use this, in angular 5 using mat-datepicker in json schema form

Comment: This should be a comment for his answer, it is not the answer to the above question.